# Cant run XMLParser as a background thread in fragment

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments, background-process

This is my first question, so sorry if I am off topic or something is wrong!
I am creating an android application and i am stuck at somewhere..
I have found tutorials and tried something like following.
The scenario is that I want to use XMLParser in my application and I am using tabs with swipable views. I want to display the items in a listview inside a tab fragment.
I have managed to get them in listview but the problem is that I cant get it to work in background. I have tried creating new thread but that doesn't work!
I think the main activity needs the fragmentview to display but it cant return a view because thread is still in progress! I hope you understand my problem..
Can anybody help me?
Here is the fragment class and xmlparser class of my application

```
gamesfragment.java

public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {
// All static variables
public static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_COST, "Rs." + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
        map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), menuItems,R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost });
    final ListView lview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lview);
    lview.setAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    //ListView lv = getListView();

    lview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
            in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
}
//xmlparser.java


public class XMLParser {

// constructor
public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
}
```

i have tried to extend my class from asynctask and put the http request from inside the doInBackground like below

```
public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {

    // All static variables
    public static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        GetStuffFromUrlTask parser1 = new GetStuffFromUrlTask();

    //  XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser1.doInBackground(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser1.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser1.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser1.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_COST, "Rs." + parser1.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser1.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), menuItems,R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost });
        final ListView lview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lview);
        lview.setAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        //ListView lv = getListView();

        lview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

private static class GetStuffFromUrlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];
        String xml = "";
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return xml;
    }
    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * @param XML string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return doc;
    }

    /** Getting node value
      * @param elem element
      */
     public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
     }

     /**
      * Getting node value
      * @param Element node
      * @param key string
      * */
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
            return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }
}

private static class ParseStuffIGotFromSomeWhereTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        String stringToParse = params[0];
        boolean result = new XMLParser().parse(stringToParse);

        return result;
    }

}

private static class XMLParser {

    public boolean parse(String string) {
        return true;
    }

}

public GamesFragment() {

    new GetStuffFromUrlTask() {

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String resultIGotFromTheTask) {

            new ParseStuffIGotFromSomeWhereTask() {

                @Override
                public void onPostExecute(Boolean resultOfTheParseTask) {

                    Log.i("Parse successful?", resultOfTheParseTask.toString());

                }

            }.execute(resultIGotFromTheTask);


        }

    }.execute(URL);

}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
}
```

I still get the error like below!

```
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:414)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:249)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:227)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at com.android.mygit.GamesFragment$GetStuffFromUrlTask.doInBackground(GamesFragment.java:125)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at com.android.mygit.GamesFragment.onCreateView(GamesFragment.java:63)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15349)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4950)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:315)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15349)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:850)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:579)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15349)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4950)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:315)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2152)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15349)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1851)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1101)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1274)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:999)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4217)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4802)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:813)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:580)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:414)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:249)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:227)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at com.android.mygit.GamesFragment$GetStuffFromUrlTask.doInBackground(GamesFragment.java:125)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at com.android.mygit.GamesFragment.onCreateView(GamesFragment.java:63)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15349)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4950)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:315)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15349)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:850)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:579)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15349)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4950)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:315)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2152)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15349)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1851)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1101)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1274)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:999)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4217)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4802)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:813)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:580)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
04-07 18:23:37.234: E/AndroidRuntime(19673):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-07 18:23:38.114: D/-heap(19673): GC_CONCURRENT freed 306K, 8% free 10130K/10951K, paused 17ms+2ms, total 64ms
```

please help!

Comment: "...but that doesn't work" is not a good error description. Any more clues? Exceptions, stacktrace...

Comment: How to make the http request in background inside XMLParser claas ????

Comment: Because my app runs successfully with this code but it takes a few seconds to make http request because it is done in main ui thread.. so i get blackscreen before the app starts!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parser is not responsible for getting something from somewhere, the parser just parses the stuff you feed to him. So create something dedicated like an AsyncTask (runs in background) which gets the stuff for you, then an AsyncTask to parse the stuff. You really should check out AsyncTask. See my example ... (it should work, I didn't actually test it ... :)
And you should probably have a look at the Google Volley library, easier HTTP stuff.

Update :

I included the fragment, (check the onCreateView, although you should maybe look for a better place than onCreateView to start your task), how the xml handler can be used to get the document and some comments how you can access the document...(again, it should work, I didn't test this and it is only to show you how to do it...)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class GameFragment extends Fragment {

// All static variables
public static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

private static class GetStuffFromUrlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];
        String xml = "";
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return xml;
    }

}

private static class ParseStuffIGotFromSomeWhereTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {

    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(String... params) {

        String stringToParse = params[0];
        Document document = new XMLParser().getDomElement(stringToParse);

        return document;
    }

}

private static class XMLParser {

    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xyz, container, false);

    //This is the task we use to parse the XML we got back from the getStuffFromUrlTask
    final ParseStuffIGotFromSomeWhereTask parseTask = new ParseStuffIGotFromSomeWhereTask() {

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Document document) {
            // here you can access the document that is the result of our parse operation

            //document.getElementsByTagName(XYZ)...

        }

    };

    //This is the task we use to get stuff from the URL
    GetStuffFromUrlTask getStuffFromUrlTask = new GetStuffFromUrlTask() {

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //The task has completed, the string result contains the XML data we got from the URL
            parseTask.execute(result); //Now we start the task to parse the xml
        }

    };

    getStuffFromUrlTask.execute(URL);

    return rootView;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this tonight :) but actually i have tried something like this . Not exactly same though! I extended my xmlparser class from asynctask but i got an error something like "  actionpending" may be becayse my application needs the return view from the gamesfragment.java to load mainactivity of the app but that wont be available as the class xmlparser will run in background! This might be the reason???

Comment: Okay should i put this in xmlparser class of my app ? Or in the gamesfragment.java?

Comment: GamesFragment, or a special dedicated class, or ... honestly it doesn't matter, it needs a place somewhere so you can call it, that's all.

Comment: I have added the code u gave me inside the gamesfragment.java and also the methods of xmlparser.java too but i still get some errors about network! I can run the app successfully if i change target sdk to 9. How to call the method doinbackground from a class which is extended from asynctask .??? I dont know how to put my code here lol :p but im trying and i hope i upload my new code here soo tht u can help me ...

Comment: I have added ny new gamesfragment.java please see in my post

Comment: You don't do it like I told you in my example. You try to call doInBackground directly, but an AsyncTask gets started with .execute(), then it runs doInBackground() in background and you get the result in onPostExecute() ... really...read the docs about AsyncTask, then you will see what you do wrong.

Comment: Then how do i call that method using .execute ? And onpostexecute? In my example?

Comment: Yeah but idk how to implement onpostexecution in this ! And get the xml string as return! Can u please help?

Comment: If i use parser1.execute(); then i dont get the string xml in return and i need that in next getdomelement method!

Comment: You get it in onPostExecute()! It runs in background, asynchronously, which means you can't get it with return without waiting on the UI thread, and you don't want to wait on the UI thread, that's why you are running it in background in the first place. You have to call execute and override onPostExecute, after some working in the background, the result of your AsyncTask operation is delivered in onPostExecute... just like I did in my example. And you should separate the getting of the XML from the parsing of the XML... just like in my example.